# Visual Studio 2012 alternative for Python built-in IDLE interactivly

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ptvs

It seems the built-in IDLE for Python has some performance degrade if too much content has been output. Is there a similar interactive console in Visual Studio for python?

Comment: Someone uses visual studio with python?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Python Tools For Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/)? It also has Ipython inbuilt.

Comment: Yes, I am using the PTVS 2012. But I didn't see an interactive console in VS2012 similar to IDLE.

Comment: PTVS 2012 has IPython inbuilt. That is a better option than IDLE right?

Comment: OK, I found it at here: http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Features%20Interactive%20REPL

Comment: I am trying to use the NLTK for python. I don't know how to integrate it into VS2012. I installed the NLTK with cpython. Seems IronPython cannot find it.

Comment: Note that you don't need IronPython for PTVS, it supports CPython just as well.